# Evaluating $\frac{d}{dx}\int_1^{x^2}\sqrt{y^2+3}dy $

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives, definite-integrals

How to Evaluate $$\frac{d}{dx}\int_1^{x^2}\sqrt{y^2+3}dy $$On doing differentiation of integration we obtain the same function but here limit of integration is also to be applied .How can we do it directly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $F(y)$ be any primitive of $f(y)=\sqrt{y^2+3}$ (you don't need to calculate it).

Then
$$\frac{d}{dx} \int_1^{x^2} \sqrt{y^2+3} \ dy = \frac{d}{dx} (F(x^2) -F(1)) = 
f(x^2)\cdot \frac{d}{dx} x^2 -0 = 2x\sqrt{x^4+3}$$

Where the second equality is calculated using the chain rule.

Answer (score 1):

This problem is not straight forward because we cannot directly apply the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus. Why is this? Because the upper limit is not $x$. In order to fix this problem we will first make the substitution $u = x^2$.

We now have:

$\int_1^{u}\sqrt{y^2+3}dy$

To calculate its derivative, we use chain rule (this is because $u = x^2$)

$\frac{d}{dx}\int_1^{u}\sqrt{y^2+3}dy = \frac{d}{du}[\int_1^{u}\sqrt{y^2+3}dy]\frac{du}{dx}$ (By Chain Rule)

$= \sqrt{u^2 + 3}*2x = 2x\sqrt{x^4 + 3}$